# decompressing portion of gz file from ftp server with go

Tags: go, ftp, gzip

I am processing large gz file from ftp server without downloading to disk with go.

I am able to fetched any portion of file via [this](https://github.com/jlaffaye/ftp) ftp go library

how can i decompress the portion that i fetched?

Comment: unclear because you don t provide enough details. This might give you some clues https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429197/reading-partially-downloaded-gzip-with-an-offset

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take something from the middle of a gzip file and decompress it. gzip files need to be decompressed from the start unless there are explicit flush points in the file (usually not) in which case data can be decompressed by starting at these flush points.

Comment: @Tamer: Unfortunately you only claim that this is not correct without providing proof of your claim. If you think that the project and paper you refer to is such a proof then you are wrong. This paper does not claim at all that it can get some arbitrary chunk from the middle of an arbitrary gzip file and decompress it. It is instead about reconstructing such data after reading lots of data starting with a random position (i.e. no arbitrary chunk of data) and under the assumption that the basic structure and content of the original data is known - in this case that these are DNA sequences.

Comment: For sure i know that the project i have sent is not answering my question. For this
reason I didn't sent as an answer and reply only your answer by saying your answer is not completely correct. Because your answer sounds like there is only one way of decompressing gzip data and no other alternative could exist. I just pointed this project this is not the case, and in case people who search about this subject can see this as an alternative.

Comment: @Tamer: In this case it would be better not to just claim that I'm not fully correct and then point to some external site as the only additional information - this way expecting everybody who wants to understand what you are talking about to invest lots of time in reading and understanding the paper. Instead you should point out where I'm exactly not correct and provide a summary of what the external site shows. This way your comment could have been a valuable contribution. As for others: the actually interesting paper is [here](https://github.com/Piezoid/pugz/blob/master/paper/paper.pdf).

Comment: Steffen thank you for your suggestions, next time i will reply more informative way instead of just pointing a link. And for sure this area is interesting and important in bioinformatics.